# SQLServer 2014 unable to achieve parallelism for query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, relational-database, sql-server-2014, sql-execution-plan

I use SQLServer 2014 (120 compatibility mode) and I want a parallel execution plan for my query, but because of a few fields, it isn't. As long as field `pi.Name AS ProcessName` is commented I have parallelism but when it is active it isn't. The same problem is with other commented fields. Is the reason connected with an index which covers `pi.ProcessGuid` but not `pi.Name` or something more?

[ExecutionPlan_Parallel](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArWMuxfCL7RbgoVV-eGX18F1T00V9g?e=obpJME)

[ExecutionPlan_Single](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArWMuxfCL7RbgoVWI_98RZ7_tjaCww?e=pZOnth)

[ExecutionPlan_Original](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArWMuxfCL7RbgoVXoS4uAYxJJHDIVQ?e=Xwpmm9)

When I commented on those few fields ExecutionPlan starts to be parallel and from 30 minutes query runs only 11 seconds.

```
SELECT kg.Id,
    ui.UserInfoGuid     AS UserGuid,
    ui.FullName         AS UserName,
    di.DeviceInfoGuid   AS DeviceGuid,
    di.ComputerFullName,
    pi.ProcessGuid,
    --pi.Name AS ProcessName,
    kg.ProcessActivationGuid,
    t.Caption,
    whi.WebsiteHostGuid,
    --whi.HostName,
    wv.WebsiteGuid,
    wv.[Url],
    --cc.CategoryGuid,
    --cc.[Name]           AS CategoryName,
    ca.ControlSequenceGuid,
    ca.ControlActivationGuid/*
    (SELECT ce.[Name] + '/' AS [text()]
    FROM   [raw].ControlElement AS ce
    WHERE  ce.ControlSequenceGuid = ca.ControlSequenceGuid
    ORDER  BY ce.SequenceNumber DESC
    FOR xml path ('')) AS ControlTree*/
    --,ac.ApplicationContextName
    ,kg.BeginDate        AS KeystrokeBeginDate
    ,kg.EndDate          AS KeystrokeEndDate
    ,kg.TotalKeyCount
    ,kg.KeyCount
    ,kg.FunctionalKeyCount
    ,kg.ClickCount
    ,kg.WheelCount
    ,kg.OtherKeyCount
    ,kg.TotalMilliseconds
    ,kg.ActiveMilliseconds
FROM raw.[Session] AS s
    INNER JOIN raw.Monitoring AS m
            ON ( m.SessionGuid = s.SessionGuid )
    INNER JOIN stats.[KeystrokeGroupRcpView] AS kg
            ON ( kg.MonitoringGuid = m.MonitoringGuid )
    INNER JOIN dbo.UserInfo AS ui
            ON ( ui.UserInfoGuid = kg.UserGuid )
    INNER JOIN dbo.DeviceInfo AS di
            ON ( di.DeviceInfoGuid = kg.DeviceGuid )
    INNER JOIN dbo.ProcessInfo AS pi
            ON ( pi.OrganizationGuid = di.OrganizationGuid
                AND pi.ProcessGuid = kg.ProcessGuid )
    INNER JOIN raw.Title AS t
            ON ( t.TitleGuid = kg.TitleGuid )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [raw].ControlActivation AS ca
                ON ca.ProcessActivationGuid = kg.ProcessActivationGuid
                    AND kg.BeginDate >= ca.BeginDate
                    AND kg.EndDate <= ca.EndDate
    LEFT OUTER JOIN controls.ControlFocus AS cf
                ON cf.ControlActivationGuid = ca.ControlActivationGuid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN controls.ControlSequenceContext AS csc
                ON csc.ControlSequenceGuid = ca.ControlSequenceGuid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN controls.ApplicationContext AS ac
                ON ac.ApplicationContextGuid = csc.ApplicationContextGuid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN controls.ProcessControlCategory AS pcc
                ON pcc.ProcessGuid = pi.ProcessGuid
                    AND pcc.ControlCategoryKeyGuid =
                        cf.ControlCategoryKeyGuid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN controls.ControlCategory AS cc
                ON cc.CategoryGuid = pcc.CategoryGuid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN raw.WebsiteVisit AS wv
                ON ( pi.IsWebBrowser = 1
                    AND wv.ProcessActivationGuid =
                        kg.ProcessActivationGuid
                    AND ( wv.BeginDate < kg.BeginDate
                                AND wv.EndDate >= kg.EndDate ) )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.WebsiteHostInfo AS whi
                ON ( whi.WebsiteHostGuid = wv.WebsiteHostGuid
                    AND whi.OrganizationGuid = di.OrganizationGuid )
WHERE kg.BeginDate > '2020-07-01' AND kg.BeginDate < '2020-07-02' and kg.UserGuid in ('A170565A-2D30-4911-5B9C-8525E2A2772B','4BE982BD-ADFC-6201-31C2-60A0BEF0D7F6','AE296576-87C6-EC2F-5A6F-E24ACE14456E')
```

Comment: Here is a quotation from the book "T-SQL Querying" by Itzik Ben-Gan "If you are trying to figure out whether your plan is not parallel as a result of the presence of an inhibitor, check the properties of the SELECT operator: property NonParallelPlanReason "

Comment: I've checked and it gives me CouldNotGenerateValidParallelPlan and nothing more

Comment: Is `pi.Name` a computed column with a scalar function?

Comment: Did you try adding the Missing Index suggested in the plan?

Comment: Looks like you got bigger issues than just parallelism. You have key lookups on `KeyStrokeGroup` `Title` `WebsiteVisit` and also `UserRcpData` lookup is non-sargeable. The other tables are using hash joins, seem they don't have efficient access methods (indexes). You may also want to update statistics on alll tables

Comment: pi.name is a standard field nvarchar(255)

Comment: What about force parallelism? Even without a suggested index, a query could give a result within 11 seconds instead of 30 minutes, could somebody explain why are those few additional fields messing with that?